Designing a multiple async/await system that is error resilient and retry capable within a multi iteration loop
I am designing a system in nodejs where I am handling 1000s of rows of user data. Each row of data will have a multiple async/await call chain to a third party endpoint, where response at each step is needed in the next step.
Logic : I am thinking of picking all the rows from the table and execute it inside a loop. Inside the loop, after completion of each async/await, just save the step#, response, status as "Complete" in the database. If all the steps are complete then marking the job as complete. Once the loop returns, then check again for any incomplete steps and start the process from that point.
Q: Is this correct way of doing it or is there a much more sophisticated way of doing this & also recovering from the errors.
Q: Also, will there be memory issues when doing this. I am running Nodejs on a small machine with 2GB RAM.
Also, I may have to slow down the execution a bit so that I do not go over the rate limiter on the third party api, if there is any.

well, ideally, the target api you're calling would have bulk endpoints that you would prefer to use for this kind of thing. Absent that, yea, you'll need to both have some form of throttling to avoid hitting their throttle, as well as some error handling to catch when such an error occurs (usually a 429 status code) so that you can wait and try again, before continuing the loop.

It's pretty hard to comment on an idea without seeing code or at least pseudo code that covers both the error handling and the recovery from errors since that's where the real meat of an implementation is. Plus, if you're doing thousands of requests to some third party host, you may have to manage requests/sec to avoid getting throttled or blocked.

It is most efficient to process such things through a pipeline that handles iterables. There are many libraries that can help with that, RxJs is the most popular, but there are many others. Library iter-ops, for one, is good for handling iterables.
